# Cannot install any package on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, dpkg, dependencies

Whenever I try to install any package, I get the following error:

`sudo apt-get install apache2`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-utils (= 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.4)
 docker-ce : Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Whenever I try to fix it, the following error occurs:

`sudo apt --fix-broken install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  wmdocker
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  docker-ce-cli
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  docker-ce-cli
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 33 not to upgrade.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 36.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 220691 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../docker-ce-cli_5%3a23.0.3-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce-cli (5:23.0.3-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce-cli_5%3a23.0.3-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/docker', which is also in package podman-docker 3.4.4+ds1-1ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/docker-ce-cli_5%3a23.0.3-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try:
`sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                                    
Get:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]                                                                        
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy InRelease                                                                                        
Get:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                                      
Get:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [992 kB]                                                           
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                            
Get:8 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [468 kB]                                
Get:9 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [102 kB]                                                       
Get:10 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [269 kB]                                                  
Get:11 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                                                 
Get:12 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [7,988 B]                                                   
Get:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [12.5 kB]                                               
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                  
Fetched 2,189 kB in 2s (1,444 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
33 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

When I try:
`sudo apt upgrade`
I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 docker-ce : Depends: docker-ce-cli but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Can someone please help? I am a noob.

Comment: @Nmath : I've added update and upgrade logs along with the question,

Comment: You should remove or disable unofficial sources and PPAs, then `update` and `upgrade` your packages in `apt`. Once your package management issues are resolved you should be able to add new software. Take care when (re)adding unofficial sources because they could create package conflicts on your system. See also: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/a/35636)

Comment: Do you have Podman installed? I guess having both Docker and Podman doesn't make much sense..